# input.change() on javascript value insert

Tags: jquery

How is it possible to trigger .change() on a javascript value insert?

Like:

```
input.val('text string insert');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the event manually:

```
input.change(function(){
    alert("change");
});

input.val('text string insert');
input.change();
```

Comment: its like calling any other function right? do val() and foo().. was that all to the question?

Comment: @zzz not really, `change()` is reserved function name, and behind the scenes it's calling the event handler attached to the `onchange` event of the element. When calling such function without any arguments, it means trigger the event, when calling with a function it means "add this function as handler".

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#txt").change(function(){    
    alert("im changed");
    });


    $("#txt").trigger('change');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2TjRu/

Answer (score 0):

This will temporary override the internal prototype.val method and the redefine it with a trigger at the end.

```
(function() {
    var ev = new $.Event('val'),
        orig = $.fn.val;
    $.fn.val= function() {
        orig.apply(this, arguments);
        $(this).trigger(ev);
    }
})();

$("#123").bind('val', function(e) {
    alert( "hi" );
});
```

Test by: $("#123").val("test");

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9mWne/